# Prove the coercivity of a function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, coercive

I have some difficulties with the following problem:

$$
f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}
$$
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} (e^{x_i} - b_ix_i)
$$

$$
b_i > 0, i = 1,..., n.
$$

I want to prove that :

- $f$ is continuous and **coercive**,
- There is at least one global minimum point.

**Note**: $f$ is called coercive if:
$$
\lim_{\left \| x \right \| \rightarrow +\infty } f(x) = + \infty 
$$

Comment: you have to tell your reader what do you mean by "coercive", this is not a standard notion and may vary from context to context

Comment: Taylor expansion gives $e^{x_i}=1+x_i+\frac{x_i^2}2+\cdots>\frac{x_i^2}2$ for $x_i>0$